# emulator hangs on start-up

Tags: android-emulator

Just starting with Android development.  Have installed Android SDK several times on a Windows XP machine following several sets of online directions and can't find the answer to my problem.

When I launch my AVD from AVD Manager, the emulator appears followed by 3 Java console windows.  The Java windows close leaving a white rectangular area over the emulator and I'm left with the hour glass icon.  It hangs at that point.  I've let it run for a long time (~30 minutes) to see if it would ever get its head out of its butt, but no luck.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This has happened to me a couple of times, and the solution -as bleak as it may be- was always to try it again. So I start the emulator, it hangs, I kill it, and start it right away. Most of the times it DOES work after this "have you tried turning it on and off again" method :)

Comment: I ran the emulator in a console window in verbose mode and the last thing I see is that it cannot connect to the ADB server on port 5555.  I'm running this in my CS lab at school, so I'm wondering if it is some network or security issue.